# sorting an array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an array ascending, but when I run it, it keep waiting for input after I entered my five numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int number[5]; //the array
    int i = 0;    //just to declare it in global scope
    int temp;    // to use it in changing posetions in the array
    for(; i < 5; i++)// getting input

    {
        cin >> number[i];
    }
    i = 0;
    for(;number[i] < 1000; i++)//this will make the biggest number on the top
    {
        if(number[i] > number[i+1])
        {
            temp = number[i];
            number[i] = number[i+1];
            number[i+1] = temp;
        }
    }
    // this will sort it by comparing it
    while(number[i] > number[i+1] || number[i+1] > number[i+2] || number[i+2] > number[i+3] || number[i+3] > number[i+3] >number[i+4])
    {
        for(;number[i] < 5; i++)
        {
            if(number[i] > number[i+1])
            {
                temp = number[i];
                number[i] = number[i+1];
                number[i+1] = temp;
            }
        }

    }
    // to output it
    i = 0;
    for(;i < 5;i++)
    {
        cout << i << " " <<number[i] << endl << endl;
    }

}
```

It output nothing after input. Actually, it keeps waiting for more input.

Comment: Sure it's not in an infinite loop? Have you stepped through it with a debugger?

Comment: `number[i+3] > number[i+3] >number[i+4]` typo?

Comment: `for(;number[i] < 5; i++)` ?

Comment: Unless you enter a number >= 1000 that second `for` loop will never terminate, and will quickly access beyond the bounds of your array.

Comment: `for(;number[i] < 1000; i++)` this likely goes straight out of the array bounds. This too: `for(;number[i] < 5; i++)`

Comment: The two loops in the middle have no bound checking at all, there's `number[i+3] > number[i+3] >number[i+4]` which is either a typo or doesn't do what you think it does, and you forgot to reset `i` in the third loop.

Comment: `while(number[i] > number[i+1] || number[i+1] > number[i+2] || number[i+2] > number[i+3] || number[i+3] > number[i+3] >number[i+4])` -- Now write code that sorts an array that has 100,000 numbers.  I know you're probably a beginner, but you have to analyze a problem first before jumping in and writing code that clearly has limited use.  You're using loops already, so you should be thinking of a solution based on `n` items, not 5.

Comment: You should review how to properly iterate over an array with a for loop. Declare your loop counters in the loop statement itself instead of declaring it outside the loop and forgetting to reset it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not waiting for input, it is stuck in an infinite loop. There are a lot of problems with your code.

**Problem 1:**

```
for(;number[i] < 1000; i++)//this will make the biggest number on the top 
    {
         if(number[i] > number[i+1])
        {
          temp = number[i];
          number[i] = number[i+1];  
          number[i+1] = temp;      
        }        
    }
```

The exit condition is the likely cause of the infinite loop. If you have no numbers greater than 999 in your array, this loop will never terminate. It is unclear to me why the exit condition depends on the contents of the array in the first place. It should depend on the value of `i`.

If you just want to swap the largest number to the end of the array, as your comment suggests, then something like this is enough (note the 4 in the exit condition, this is to avoid index out of bounds errors):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)//this will make the biggest number on the top 
    {
         if(number[i] > number[i+1])
        {
          temp = number[i];
          number[i] = number[i+1];  
          number[i+1] = temp;      
        }        
    }
```

**Problem 2:**

```
while(number[i] > number[i+1] || number[i+1] > number[i+2] || number[i+2] > number[i+3] || number[i+3] > number[i+3] >number[i+4])
    {
     for(;number[i] < 5; i++)
    {
         if(number[i] > number[i+1])
        {
          temp = number[i];
          number[i] = number[i+1];  
          number[i+1] = temp;      
        }        
    }

    }
```

Again, the exit conditions are a real mess. The while-loop's exit condition is unnecessarily complicated, you shouldn't try to "brute-force check" in such a way. The for-loop's exit condition again depends on the contents of the array.

**Problem 3:**

It looks like you forgot to add `i = 0;` between the first for-loop and the while loop. In general, I recommend you write for-loop headers like so: `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`. This way you will avoid these kinds of errors, or at least reduce their numbers significantly.

**Problem 4:**

It's generally good practice to refrain from using constants in exit conditions. So, instead of writing something like: `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`, it is better to write: `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`, where `n` is an integer variable. This way, your code is more general and is much easier to modify.

**Conclusion:**

It looks to me like what you're trying to implement here is [BubbleSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). I suggest you rewrite your program in a more concise way (**HINT**: the sorting part can be done with two for-loops). I refrain from writing the code for you, as with the information in the link and my suggestions, this should be fairly easy to do.

I would also suggest that you think about a problem in general terms. So, in this case, don't think about how to sort an array of five elements, but think about how to sort an array of n elements (i.e. of arbitrary length). This will help guide your thinking to a correct and sound solution.

Best of luck!